# GO : cors - Http Status 503 - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: go

I have an API made in Go, and a Front in Angular.

When i ping that url : *https://myDomain/v1/users/sign/up*
Angular is trying to do an **OPTIONS** request.

I saw on some topics that I have to setup cors in my API, that's what I did:

In my `main.go` file:

```golang
servMuxApi := http.NewServeMux()
user.SetUserRoute(servMuxApi)

c := cors.SetupCors()
handler := c.Handler(servMuxApi)

if err := http.ListenAndServe(servPort, handler); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

In the `SetUserRoute` function i just have a `HandleFunc`:

```
router.HandleFunc("/v1/users/sign/up", SignUpUser)
```

`SetupCors` function :

```
func SetupCors() *cors.Cors {
    return cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:8081*", "chrome-extension://coohjcphdfgbiolnekdpbcijmhambjff"},
        AllowedMethods:   []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodPost, http.MethodPut, http.MethodPatch, http.MethodDelete, http.MethodOptions},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        OptionsPassthrough: true,
        })
    }
}
```

***NB: the chrome extension you see is the Postman extension i use on Chrome.***

With all of that set i'm still having errors on the Google Chrome console when i try my Angular front Sign Up form :

**OPTIONS https://myDomain/v1/users/sign/up 503**

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myDomain/v1/users/sign/up' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

EDIT: the problem is, that, on the Chrome console, i don't see that Respone
[image]

Comment: fix this `router.HandleFunc("https://myDomain/v1/users/sign/up", SignUpUser)` to `router.HandleFunc("/v1/users/sign/up", SignUpUser)` might solve the problem. unclear, I suspect you should check for the server handling responses in the command line output using something like https://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#LoggingHandler

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment, i already did it, that's an error on my stackoverflow question, i'll fix it.

Comment: have you correctly configured the allowed origin in `AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:8081*", "chrome-extension://coohjcphdfgbiolnekdpbcijmhambjff"},` ?

Comment: I think i did... When i check the google chrome console i see that :
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Referer: http://localhost:8081/layouts/register

So i think that http://localhost:8081* is the origin no ?

Comment: are you reverse proxying ?....

Comment: Yes i am, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally understood the problem.
I use **CloudFlare** *(https://www.cloudflare.com)* to set some security on my server.
But on CloudFlare the **"under attack mode"** variable was set to **"ON"** -> Prohibiting every request on my API.
After setting this to off, every request work. So the problem didn't come from my API or my Front.
My API was well set...

If you use a Reverse Proxy, or some firewalls, please be very careful with your configurations we had a lot of conflicts.

Thank you very much to **@Or Yaacov** and **@mh-cbon** for helping me.
Hope this answer will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

please add the following allowed headers:
(replace the wild card "*" with your app-data headers)

```
AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "*"},
```

a full example that compatible with Angular (I used gorilla/mux in the following):

```
//Start starting the http server
func Start() {
    router := NewRouter()
    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "*"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"POST", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})
    http.Handle("/api/", handlers.CORS(headersOk, originsOk, methodsOk)(http.StripPrefix("/api", router)))
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":"+utils.Config.ServerPort, nil))
}
```

Edit:
you should make sure that your response contains all of the "allowed headers" as we defined to the OPTIONS request:
[image]

Comment: Hello, What is the "handlers" variable when you use
handlers.AllowedHeaders
handlers.AllowedOrigins
....

Comment: it's just an example, you should add only the allowed headers

Comment: Now it looks like that but still not working... 
`AllowedOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:8081*", "chrome-extension://coohjcphdfgbiolnekdpbcijmhambjff"},
AllowedMethods:     []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodPost, http.MethodPut, http.MethodPatch, http.MethodDelete, http.MethodOptions},
AllowedHeaders:     []string{"Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "*"},
AllowCredentials:   true,
OptionsPassthrough: true,
`

Comment: whats the error that you are getting? it's not pass the OPTION request?

Comment: @SachsA the most important question is if you see the new headers in your http response from the server, I edited my answer and added a screenshot.
it will be very helpful if you will upload a screen shot too, so we will be able to see the response headers

Comment: I edited my stack overflow question ! That's exactly the point ! I don't see the response on the chrome console !

Comment: please try the following example
https://github.com/rs/cors/blob/master/examples/nethttp/server.go
with the following cors:
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
  AllowedOrigins:     []string{"http://localhost:8081*", "chrome-extension://coohjcphdfgbiolnekdpbcijmhambjff"},
  AllowedHeaders:     []string{"Content-Type", "Origin", "Accept", "*"},
  AllowedMethods:     []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodPost, http.MethodPut, http.MethodPatch, http.MethodDelete, http.MethodOptions},
  AllowCredentials:   true,
  OptionsPassthrough: true,
 })

Comment: @SachsA if it doesn't work just don't relay on there package. 
just create a middleware that capture all of the OPTIONS request and add the headers
or use a routing library, Gin will be my choose

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you can see my answer above... The problem didn't come from my API.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone stumbling on this thread in the future. After 2 hours of headache I found a solution that has not been mentioned yet. I set all my options headers in express to allow cors and I downloaded/enabled the cors package as everyone else has said. I also was able to send a POST request to localhost:8000, but NOT through the ngrok tunnel.

UNTIL I went here https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken and set my authtoken in the ngrok terminal. Then I ran this command ngrok http 8000 -host-header="localhost:8000"

Maybe it'll work for you, maybe it won't, I'm not 100% sure what this is doing. But try authenticating with your ngrok token and see if that works.